# Does a soul retain it's identity after Moksha?

Tags: moksha

I know my question is counterintuitive since the entire idea of Moksha is merging with the Supreme.

Comment: Your question has two components.  Moksha and recollect of past lives. Header and body of content is not same. Please clarify your question

Comment: Jivatma can recollect past lives yes. But what is your question? You are asking if jiva retains identity in title and asking about past lives in body of content.

Comment: There are five kinds of Moksha. In that Kaivalya Moksha is the Moksha where individuality is dissolved into Supreme. In other forms of Moksha identity do exist in world of Brahma.

Comment: According to advaita, yes and no. there are 2 schools as to when. One school says immediately upon death final liberation is attained and your 'soul' (jiva is a better description) is merged and loses it's idenity, the other school says at the end of the present kalpa, so your 'identity' as an individual jiva would retain until then. In either case, your individual identity ceases upon final liberation.

Answer (score 3):

A good question.

The answer is yes.

**Fate of the Liberated soul**

> Except over-lordship (on the world), they become equal to Brahma in
> affluence, glory, form (appearance) and objects.

**Vayu Purana I.7.29**

The liberated Jiva does not get the power to create, preserve and destroy the universe. Those powers are reserved for Brahma, Vishnu and Siva. They certainly get all other powers including omniscience.